# MFMessageComposeViewController did not Support iOS 8

Tags: mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@", LOCALIZED(@"Angkor Auto"), car.name];
    controller.body = @"";
            NSString* trim = [MGUtilities removeDelimetersInPhoneNo:_contactNo];

    if(_smsNo != nil)
        trim = [MGUtilities removeDelimetersInPhoneNo:_contactNo];

    controller.recipients = @[ trim, ];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.view.backgroundColor = BG_VIEW_COLOR;

    }
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:nil completion:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    }];

}
```

Comment: Why is it not working ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include what, specifically, isn't working, and how. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!